# Sending a message from unity webGL to vue page embedding it

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, vuejs2, unity-webgl

I have a vue webpage with a unity WebGL contained within it. Now I would like to be able to send a message (JSON and image) from unity to the vue page.

I already know how to do the reverse (sending a string from vue to unity)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { mapState, mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import Unity3dViewer from '../3d-viewer/3d-viewer';

export default {
   methods: {
        PlaceItem: function(){

            alert("placed object" )
            var data = Unity3dViewer.data();
            data.gameInstance.SendMessage("BrowserCommunication", "PlaceLight", Vue.prototype.$productID);
        },
    }
}
```

However, I can't quite figure out how to get the inverse to work. I have looked at [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html). But when I try to put the function into the methods

```
 export default {
   methods: {
     mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {

      Hello: function () {
        window.alert("Hello, world!");
       },
  }) 
}}
```

It doesn't compile (it expects a, instead of a . at LibraryManager.library).

I have also found [this](https://github.com/votetake/vue-unity-webgl) which promises two-way communication but only documents one way.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a semicolon at the end of the `})`. You also don't need the `,` at the end of `}` unless you have another function below that which you don't at this moment so remove that comma.

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  Hello: function(param) {
    alert(Pointer_stringify(str));
  }
});
```

The C# side:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void Hello (string message);
```

See [this](https://npm.taobao.org/package/react-native-unity-webgl#calling-javascript-functions-within-react-from-unity-scripts) page for information about vue-unity plugin.

Below is a basic plugin example for sending or returning values to and from a Javascript plugin without any external plugin:

**Javascript:**

```
var PluginName = {

    //Function without argument 
    GetMessage: function(){
        var level = "Hello World!";

        var buffer = _malloc(lengthBytesUTF8(level) + 1);
        writeStringToMemory(level, buffer);
        return buffer;
    },

    //Function with argument 
    SendMessage: function(param){
        alert(Pointer_stringify(str));
    }
};
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, PluginName);
```

**C#:**

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern string GetMessage();

[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void SendMessage(string str);

void Start()
{
    string message = GetMessage();
    Debug.Log("Message: " + message);

    SendMessage("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: How do I put this into vue?

Comment: With my second example, name the file "PluginName.jslib` then put it in the `Assets/Plugins/WebGL` folder

Comment: Sure, what I mean is how do I get a vue component to listen to the messages?

Comment: I am confused. I though you wanted to send message from Unity to webgl javascript? This shows you how to do that which is how to call a Javascript function from Unity. Is there a problem?

Comment: I want to send data from unity to vue, I can send data from vue to unity and from unity to a javascript thing but I can't get the data into vue (well right now the line `__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.store.state.unityObject=json; `appears to work under the right conditions, but it's far from perfect as it requires the vue devtools).

Comment: Also if anyone wants to copy the `__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.store.state.unityObject=json` you will need the vue dev tools installed on the user's browser or it won't work.